# Qt - TableView Header Data became invisible?

Tags: c++, qt

My TableView was showing header data earlier and I kept on working on my software on a completely different part and somehow while testing I realized that the header data was completely gone, although I could see the lists. Note that "SetHeaderVisible" thing is enabled in the Qt Editor. This is the code I used to set the header:

```
itemModel = new QStandardItemModel();

    //setting Column count and labeling them
    itemModel->setColumnCount(5);
    itemModel->setHeaderData(0, Qt::Horizontal, "Item Name");
    itemModel->setHeaderData(1, Qt::Horizontal, "Price");
    itemModel->setHeaderData(2, Qt::Horizontal, "Date Released");
    itemModel->setHeaderData(3, Qt::Horizontal, "Bugs");
    itemModel->setHeaderData(4, Qt::Horizontal, "Suggestions");
    //set the itemModel to TableView
    ui->tableView->setModel(itemModel);
```

Comment: isn't this kinda thing what sv/git etc is for...

Comment: Please review this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve